# What is the fastest way to check if a element of a multidimensional map exist?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose n is some known fixed number. Suppose I make an n dimensional map like so

```
map < int , map < int, map < /* ... */ < int, map< int, double > > /*...*/ > mymap;
```

What is the fastes wat to check if say element `mymap[a][b]...[n]` exist?

EDIT: This question is different from the duplicate because it generalizes the duplicate question to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Using that syntax, it will "exist" whether you want it or not, as `operator[]` throws it into the underlying map if it isn't already there regardless. You probably want to use [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) and check the iterator(s) for the underying map's `end()`. Or a pair of `count` invokes.

Comment: In this case I would not use a "map of maps" data structure but only one map with a multidimensional key type such as `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: Even you can use `mymap.at(i).at(j)` and rely on exception `std::out_of_range` if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With something like this (using a lambda here for demonstration purposes only):

```
bool exists = [&my_map](int i, int j) -> bool
{
    auto it = my_map.find(i);
    return it != my_map.end() && it->second.find(j) != it->second.end();
};
```

Usage:

```
if (exists(i, j)) { /* ... */ }
```

---

For the recursive case, I'd use a templated overload set:

```
bool exists(const std::map<int, double>& m, int key)
{
    return m.find(key) != m.end();
}

template <typename... Args, typename ...Krgs>
bool exists(const std::map<int, Args...>& m, int key, Krgs ...keys)
{
    auto it = m.find(key);
    return it != m.end() && exists(it->second, keys...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to generalize this to n dimensions?

Comment: @MariusJonsson: Probably, somehow, probably with templates. Just keep passing `it->second` down to the next level of existence check.

Comment: Hmm, exactly how to you recommend? Is it possible to edit the answer to add a generalization for say 4-dimensional maps?

Comment: @MariusJonsson: Only if you edit the question to state an understandable goal.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @MariusJonsson: OK, have a look now ([demo](http://ideone.com/PL4JD0)).

Comment: Wow! This is the most impressive code I have seen in my life. What does this exists(it->second, keys...); do? Why did you have to declare the exists function twice? And what happens in this line: bool exists(const std::map<int, Args...>& m, int key, Krgs ...keys) ? Thank you so much!